# Php array to woocommerce dynamic select options

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a PHP array like below and I would like to convert this to options format like structure seen below:

```
Array(

[0] => Array
    (
        [server_varient_model] => test_1
        [server_varient_id] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [server_varient_model] => test_2
        [server_varient_id] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [server_varient_model] => test_3
        [server_varient_id] => 3
    ))
```

I want this output as,

```
'options' => array(
 '1'   => __( 'test_1', 'woocommerce' ),
 '2'   => __( 'test_2', 'woocommerce' ),
 '3'   => __( 'test_3', 'woocommerce' ),
)
```

Help me to solve this.

Comment: Do you have some code? You need to try a little before posting on SO.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be what you are looking for:

```
$options = array();
foreach($input as $inp)
{
    $options[$inp['server_varient_id']] = __($inp['server_varient_model'],  'woocommerce' );    
}
print_r($options);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, I thought in woo-commerce need the structure same like this

`__( 'test_1', 'woocommerce' ),`

But i refer some more sites and found the solution,no need this structure just only need a

`key_value pair array`,

here is my answer,

```
foreach($platform_list as $arr){
         $vvr[$arr->server_varient_id]=$arr->server_varient_model;
}
```

Here is a reference link,

http://php.wekeepcoding.com/article/10289818/Populating+Woocommerce+Variation+Custom+Select+Field+Options+From+Database